# Where can I find source code and build instructions of supported codec by FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to build FFmpeg from source on CentOS 6.7 using below Config options:

```
--enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r 
--enable-iconv
--enable-gnutls  --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca
--enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc
--enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp
--enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtwolame
--enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc
--enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libxavs
--enable-decklink
--enable-zlib
```

Where can I find the documentation for  the location of source code and compilation instruction for different Codec supported by FFmpeg?

Do I have to google for every option above to find the source code and compilation instruction on CentOS/RedHat Linux platform?

Comment: By the way, I have issues with only the FFmpeg config options I have listed above.  I have build FFmpeg using several Codec as per information from ffmpeg.org. However, I am not able to find the information on building FFmpeg using most of the above config option. Looks like this information is scattered all across the web.

Comment: Are you sure you need all of those options? Many are for external libraries of oddball formats (webp, schroedinger, modplug, etc). Perhaps you should tell us what you want `ffmpeg` to do then we will know what options you really need.

Comment: I am trying to explore this option. And I am not able to find the correct way to  identify additional information. I need to support HLS and RTMP streaming at the minimum and also need segmentation support for which I do not need to compile FFmpeg with any additional flags as per my knowledge...or do I ? I am streaming from Object Store. So segmentation support is must.  To secure the URL of the video. With the help of this feature user would not be able to know the exact path of the media. So he/she would not be able to download the video.

Comment: FFmpeg has native support for HLS and RTMP. I'm assuming you'll want to output H.264 video; so far that means you only need `--enable-gpl --enable-libx264`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Where can I find the information  about what is natively supported ? I have been going through the ffmpeg.org and must have clearly missed this information. Would you mind sharing that URL? And what about the segmentation ? Does it also supported natively as long as I install the latest version of ffmpeg from github?